# How to proceed reviewing once reaching limits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, flags, community

Suppose a *relatively* (definition might be vague) new user is ambitious and wants to learn the site's dynamic flow by e.g. regularly reviewing posts. Besides it profiting the site as a whole you also learn bunch of new StackOverflow functions, rules and formalities.

*Anyhow, the reasoning to why someone reviews isn't important.* My question is about the flag and edit limits new users face, i.e.

> You only can raise 10 flags per day

and

> You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved

respectively. The existence of mentioned limitations is clearly justified and important for the moderators / privileged users, though my question deals with the reviewing users:

Shall someone, once reached the daily editing and flagging limit, **stop** with reviewing? Just "**skip**ping" if a bad question appears *(kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it?)*? Is it better to **wait** till the limits have been lifted?

If possible, please shed some light on this "problem" from different angles, i.e. what is better for the site? the mods? etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is: Are you asking why are there limits for flags and edits, or are you asking what users should do when they've reached those limits and still have reviews that they *could* do?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I'm asking what a user should do if they still have reviews, but are limited due to not having any flags or edits available. Shall the user stop? wait? skip if an occurence of mentioned type appears? This question isn't answerable by a single entity, hence the `discussion` tag. Best would be to hear different opinions and/or cited rules (if there are any - though I didn't find anything). Those insights can be granted from a variety of angles, e.g. what benefits StackOverflow as a whole, what benefits the mods, etc.